# Final stock availablity value [magento]

Tags: magento

I would like to find out the stock availability for a product in the catalog after checking for the quantity and the "in stock" dropdown option.

Is there a method to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isSalable

Comment: Thanks. Works just like I needed it to.